# Map not showing up when using react-map-gl and create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am using create react app, along with `react-map-gl`. I just need the map to show up on the screen right now but all it does is show the mapbox logo and have a blank space where the map should be.
Here is my main .js file:

```
    import './App.css';
    import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';
    import React, {useState} from 'react';

    function App() {
      const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        latitude: 38.958630,
        longitude: -77.357002,
        zoom: 10
      });
      return (
        <div className="TextStuff">
          <ReactMapGL {...viewport}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}>MAPPPPP</ReactMapGL>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

[image: The map should be appearing here, as you can see the mapbox logo pops up, but the mapp does not]

Comment: It can be linked to the react-map-gland mapbox-gl version. What version do you use?

Comment: I am using version 2.6.1 for mapbox-gl and version 6.1.18 for react-map-gl

Comment: And is your token valid ? Did you defined it in some .env file ? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Yeah my token is valid, I checked with there thing https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/page.html?access_token=MYTOKEN and I do not get any console errors

Comment: And you are sure it is not undefined when passing it to the ReactMapGL component?

Comment: Yes I am, I don't think it would be able to show the mapbox logo and have it be sized properly if it was, I was having that problem earlier but I didn't have mapbox-gl installed properly

Comment: I don't think that you set the token correctly. Could you show how do you try to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating, I came to the conclusion that your token is not properly passed to your component, through the `process.env`. I created a [reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-test-ivbkv?file=/src/App.js), with a working token, and it is working like a charm. I am getting the same result as you when providing an invalid token.
So I guess that you are getting and undefined token, or something like this.

Following this [tutorial](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), you should have an `.env` file, where you store your token like this:
`REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN=MYTOKEN`

Try to log out your `process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN`, to see what you are getting.

But what I suspect, is that you put the `.env` file in your src folder.  But you shouldn't put it there. Instead, put it at the root of your project, and then restart your server. This way, you should get your token correctly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I think I did something stupid and I didn't have my .env inside my actual app directory.